# R "Can not retrieve results. No valid internet connection" on googleway

Tags: r, curl, proxy, googleway

Im trying to use the `googleway::google_places` functon in R but I dont know how to set the proxy options.

I believe googleway uses the package `curl` instead of `rcurl`.

I get the error :  **Can not retrieve results. No valid internet connection (tested using curl::has_internet() )**

My code:

```
google_places(search_string = "Agence societe Generale, Paris 75015",
              key = key)
```

Comment: Are you the same person who posted this on my [github issues page](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/166) too?

Comment: Yes it was me!!